# Google drive website upload Failed Upload HTTP error (6)

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a website to upload a file to Google Drive from my website, but I have had a lot of trouble.
I have used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save to Drive Demo: Explicit Render</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://samrobbins.125mb.com/googledrive.html">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">
      {parsetags: 'explicit'}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="render-link">Render the Save to Drive button</a>
    <div id="savetodrive-div"></div>
    <script>
      function renderSaveToDrive() {
        gapi.savetodrive.render('savetodrive-div', {
                src: 'http://samrobbins.125mb.com/knowledgebase.py',
          filename: 'Cat.py',
          sitename: 'The electronic cat database'
        });
      }
      document.getElementById('render-link').addEventListener('click', renderSaveToDrive);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I load it, it says there is `Failed Upload HTTP error (6)`

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: drop the /googledrive.html also add the Access Control headers. I am getting an error that there is no Access Control header on the resource - that's why it's not downloading

Answer (score 0):

http error 6 is could not resolve host name. Your server may be down or the data-src server may be down. Try later.

You are sharing from a google drive. the default visibility of a google drive doc is private. You should change this to public.

Check the box next to a file/folder and click the Share button at the top of your file list